# How to remove rounded corners from leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, styles, leaflet, rounded-corners

I want to make the edges of my leaflet popup box sharp (corners) instead of rounded edges. I have downloaded the source `leaflet-src.js` but can't seem to find where the this is happening. Places I've looked for are in the class:

```
   leaflet-popup-content-wrapper
   leaflet-popup-content
   leaflet-popup-close-button
```

Does anyone know where this is happening?

Answer (score 9):

you can override the default style by adding !important key word

For example:- put this class inside your page this will over ride the border style

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,.leaflet-popup-content
{
 border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

For multiple browser support

```
 .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,.leaflet-popup-content
 {
   -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
   -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
 }
```

First thing is that you have to find which tag is making the radius and over ride that class you can use the developer tool for identifying that.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used leaflet.js, but this sounds like a CSS issue more than Javascript. The `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper` class has `border-radius: 12px`, which seems relevant. [Specified here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/dist/leaflet.css#L390) in the source.